# Unity project. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I make a build for iPhone for the first time and got a problem.
I already checked a lot of posts and didnt find answer. 
When i make a build on device a get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"RegisterAllStrippedInternalCalls()", referenced from:
RegisterAllInternalCalls() in libiPhone-lib.a(MonoICallRegistration.o)
"RegisterAllClasses()", referenced from:
InitializeEngineNoGraphics() in libiPhone-lib.a(SaveAndLoadHelper.o)
"RegisterMonoModules()", referenced from:
_main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On simulator ok. 
libiPhone-lib.a added to link libraries.
Can somebody tell what it is? Please

Comment: possible duplicate of [XCode 4.5 - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250986/xcode-4-5-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7)

Comment: already tried. not working for me.

Comment: XCode 4.5 - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 DOESNT HELP

Comment: can you supply more details? what is your deployment target? and Unity version?

Answer (score 0):

Your unity version is not compatible, just download the latest version of unity which I believe is 4.3.1 and try recompiling. Here is the link if you need it. http://unity3d.com/unity/download/download-mac

The new version is compatible with armv7.

Answer (score 0):

ok if anyone else is experiencing the same problem here's a way out:

those 3 methods mentioned are declared in the RegisterMonoModules.cpp in the Libraries folder, usually. so take that cpp file and add it to your target's Build Phases > Compile Sources

then if you have additional SDK's integrated that are not added to the 'Compile Sources' the new build will throw some other errors. just make sure to add the wrapper .mm files from the sdk's to your Compile Sources. Usually one .mm file per sdk. (e.g. for unity facebook sdk it's FbUnityInterface.mm file)

hope this helps